# SAGE roots on the root field

Tags: math, sage

I want to find the roots of a polynomial under a finite field. So I computate what follows:

```
sage: R.<x>=PolynomialRing(GF(9,'a'))
sage: f=x^3+2*x+1
sage: K.<alpha>=f.root_field()
sage: f.roots(ring=K)
```

But it does not work, it shows me this error:

```
ValueError: factorization of 0 not defined
```

And I can't find what is happening.
Could somebody help me with that?

Comment: What is the output for `K`? Or is the error already in that step?

Answer (score 2):

Sage doesn't support relative extensions of finite fields really.   (It would be nice if it did, but it doesn't -- somebody add that functionality, please.)  One can find the roots at least in an absolute field, as follows:

```
F.<alpha> = GF(3^6)
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(F)
f = x^3+2*x+1
f.roots()
```

This outputs:

```
  [(2*alpha^5 + 2*alpha^4, 1), (2*alpha^5 + 2*alpha^4 + 2, 1), (2*alpha^5 + 2*alpha^4 + 1, 1)]
```

https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/4a5f0542-5873-4eed-a85c-a18c706e8bcd/files/support/2015-03-30-112034-root-stack-overflow.sagews

Comment: Ok thank you very much, it reeally worked for me. What I need is to work with extensions, Galois groups, discriminants... so I really need non tipically examples (rationals and complexes) so I fins for examples as finite fields.

Answer (score 0):

Magma tells me

```
> G<a>:=GaloisField(9);
> P<x>:=PolynomialRing(G);
> p:=x^3+2*x+1;
> Roots(p);
[]
Q<z>:=SplittingField(p); Q;
Finite field of size 3^6
> Roots(p,Q);
[ <z^28, 1>, <z^84, 1>, <z^252, 1> ]
```

so apparently there is a problem either in the invocation with `ring=K` or in the implementation of sage. Is there an example where your sequence of commands works flawlessly?